# What is the Google Chrome Inspector?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is Google Chrome Inspector another name for Google DevTools, or is it a specific part of Google DevTools, which one then? I hear the term "Google Chrome Inspector" name a lot but do not see any mention of it in the this official google link: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools

Comment: No, inspector is the nickname of just one panel in devtools: the elements inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just another way of saying "Chrome DevTools".

People say "Inspector" because if you right click anywhere withing Chrome the menu that opens has an option called "Inspect". Clicking this "Inspect" option opens Chrome DevTools.

It also make sense because the DevTools allow one to "Inspect" what's going on behind the UI curtain so to speak.

Comment: Would it be safe to say then that Chrome DevTools is the official name because it seems like Google does not use the term Chrome Inspector on their links but other sources do?